# How the iOS can access to apple watch and airpod at the same time?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, apple-watch

I thought the Bluetooth module can connect to only one another device, but iPhone(or any iOS device) can be connected with Apple Watch and AirPod at the same time.
How can it be possible? Is there any additional module in iOS device?
If yes, why can't i make another double connection except Apple Watch or AirPods?

Comment: Not a programming related question (not without serious revising, at least). Try [su] or [apple.se]?

Comment: @rickster thanks. I'll try it :)